# Does the Potion of Herb Tracking stack on the same follower?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft Battle for Azeroth, I have a follower that has 2 equipment slots. If I put two [Potion of Herb Tracking](https://www.wowhead.com/item=162113/potion-of-herb-tracking) on that follower, will I have two chances of getting a herb return? Or will it only give the buff once, and not stack?

Comment: From reading Wowhead comments that seems to work, and I would expect that to be fine. It's double stacking on a single follower that I'd expect Blizz to disapprove of. I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: Yeah I had read that 2 followers would probably have the chance to 'double proc'. was hoping two on the same char would be the same!

Comment: Things like that always stacked. I used to have the gold on world quests trait in all three slots on my bodyguard follower in Legion. You could not use the same item multiple times, but different items with the same effect worked well.

Comment: I think it’s unique equipped, making it impossible to have 2 on 1 follower.

Comment: Yea, like in Legion. But having multiple items on multiple followers do stack, just like having multiple (different) items with the same effect on one.

Comment: Stay away from these items. They are gold sinks. It takes *months* of running missions 24/7 until you get the investment back, and even longer to turn a profit. The drop chance is *extremely* poor.

Comment: @Polygnome then shouldn’t I make it right away so I can get the best return? The more mission I do, the more I make.

Comment: @Childishforlife If you think thats a good usage of your gold. But honestly, you can do pretty much everything else with your gold and have a higher return on investment. If you want to make gold, those things are pretty much the worst investment you can make.

Comment: In Legion you couldn't equip two of the same item on a follower.  I doubt that's changed in BfA.  At least in Legion you could get around that by using different items that had the same effect.

Comment: @Polygnome has it right. I _still_ haven't put any equipment on any followers; it's (so far) a complete waste of time and gold.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to equip a follower with two potions of herb tracking, as they are unique-equip.

Comment: All follower equipment is unique.  This was true in Legion, too.